# For each to For Loop Conversion

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

May I know how do I convert the following for each loop to a normal for loop?

```
for (SortedMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mapDefect.entrySet())
```

I have a `count` variable as the starting point and the end of the map as the end point. So accordingly how may I convert it into a normal for loop?

Comment: So, to be clear, you just want to look from the `count`-th element till the end of the map?

Comment: @irrelephant Nope. I want to start from the 'count' variable till the end of the map.

Comment: Many IDEs offer to convert for loop types for you. These change the code and add any variables as required.  It is faster and less error prone.  I would see what your IDE can do for you.  BTW it is `Map.Entry` not `SortedMap.Entry`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say the task is to skip the first `count` elements, and process the rest.

This can be done with either a "for" loop, or a "for each" loop. In this case, I'd keep this as a "for each" loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (SortedMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mapDefect.entrySet()) {
   if (i++ < count) continue;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yup - I don't see a reason to move to an iterator either.

Answer (score 8):

[Section 14.14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) gives the translation. In this case, it would be roughly:

```
for (Iterator<SortedMap.Entry<Integer, String>> iterator
         = mapDefect.entrySet().iterator();
     iterator.hasNext(); )
{
    SortedMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry = iterator.next();
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [`Iterables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) class to take a section of the sorted set:

```
Iterable<SortedMap.Entry<Integer, String>> section = Iterables.limit(
    Iterables.skip(mapDefect.entrySet(), start), end - start);
for (SortedMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry : section) {
    // ...
}
```

Or if it's *just* from `count` (with the clarifying comment):

```
for (SortedMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry :
         Iterables.skip(mapDefect.entrySet(), count)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you still need to add the count variable with the iterator approach, in which case the for-each supported with a count variable is fine as well. IMO there is no direct way to switch from for-each to for with a count variable (like the one available for an array)

Comment: @Scorpion: The first part of my answer is converting the enhanced for loop to a "normal" one. The second part of my answer is an alternative approach to iterate over just a section of the set.

Comment: @Scorpion: It would be a lot simpler in C# with LINQ and extension methods, of course ;) Still, Java 8...

Comment: @Scorpion & Jon Skeet Hey! Thanks. Solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to iterate of a map is using an iterator or a for-each loop (which uses an iterator).

Converting your for each loop to a "normal" loop **can** work in your case, because you are using Integers as map keys:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapDefect.size(); i++) {
  String value = mapDefect.get(i)
  // do something with value
}
```

But note that this only works if you are using map keys as you would use array/list indices (which makes the map useless).
To use this kind of loop you have to use consecutive positive integers as map keys starting at 0